# Changing the ports a program uses

Tags: networking, firewall, gaming, udp, steam

This question might not even make sense. I have a very limited understanding of how networking protocols work. My phrasing of these questions might be very poor.

My school has a firewall enabled. Running the online version of Firebind tells me that there are very few accessible UDP ports. A program I'd like to run, Lord of the Rings Online, requires that ports 9000-9010 and 2900-2910 be available. Is it at all possible for me to "reroute" these ports within my computer? In essence, telling programs that want to use these ports to use other ports. Ones that I can verify are open. Steam works, for example. Could I theoretically tell a program to use the same ports as Steam?

Comment: No; You cannot change the ports a program wants to use unless it provides that capability. Are you sure the ports even have to be forwarded. The type of connection LOTRO uses should not require specific ports to be forwarded.  **Its only if those ports are specifically blocked from being used is it required.**

Comment: it actually sounds like from your error that you don;t need forwarded ports, but that too many are in use. that likely means that on the public side of the firewall nat, other computer users are useing those ports. remember when behind a nat, you only have 65535 UDP ports for all computers behind the nat, not just your own.

Comment: School might restrict access to such ports for purpose of preventing from such games being used on the school network.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to route ports internally (can't find it right now unfortunately.), but given that the firewall you're facing is not on your computer, this won't work.

Do keep in mind, that the reason they put up a firewall is to prevent this kind of activity in the first place.

Your best bet would be to use something to take over your pc at home such as `logmein`, `teamviewer`, `vnc`, etc. and control the game like that. Performance will be poor though, so it might not work either.

EDIT: I mentioned route would make port mappings, but I'm confused with a different program that I can't think of what its name is.

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows `route` command?

Comment: yes, I am referring to the Windows `route` command.

Comment: I'm not aware that the Windows `route` command does anything other than modify the routing table. How is it that it can modify the ports that applications use?

Comment: You can add routing tables to route the traffic from one port to another. So traffic that is looking at port 500 can be routed directly to port 9000, etc.

Comment: With the Windows `route` command? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I could, but I recommend researching the `route` command on the internet yourself. The reason I say this, is because the `route` command is a very powerful command. If you make an error, you can easily break your network/internet connection.

Comment: The Windows `route` command does no such thing. I asked you to provide an example to see if you could and you didn't... because the Windows route command cannot modify the port a program uses. The Windows `route` command is used to display and modify the IP routing table. - http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I just checked because you seems so sure and you are indeed right, and I want to apologise @joeqerty. Seems I used a different tool at work. Can't find a reference to that tool unfortunately, but it was indeed not route.

Comment: No worries. I thought that maybe I was seriously misunderstanding the `route` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do it. The solution could be a http tunnel (or other port that It is not blocked by the firewall, e.g), but I don't believe that the IDS (and the Firewall) that I hope that Your school has.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I fully grasp the specifics of the problem, but in situations where there is an intermediate component that is blocking traffic that you cannot control, the best way to circumvent it is to route all relevant traffic through a VPN.  This can even work for incoming connections.  It may be tricky if your application is using UPNP, perhaps a bridged VPN solution might be best...  You will need an external server that you can control to act as the VPN server.  You will most likely experience a high amount of latency.

Let me know in comments if you want a detailed how-to...

Other solutions may include some kind of remote desktop / VNC Type solutions, but will probably have even worse latency

On a related note: Perhaps a better and more direct solution would be to make friends with someone in their IT and buy them a beer or something :)